# Instagram Business Discovery API Pagination Token not working?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api

I am trying to use Instagram Business Discovery API to get post statistics from a certain public page.

Take Bath and Body Works (https://www.instagram.com/bathandbodyworks) for example.

```
GET graph.facebook.com
   17895695668004550?fields=business_discovery.username(bathandbodyworks){followers_count,media_count,media{timestamp,like_count,comments_count}}
```

This will give me the following response:

```
{
"business_discovery": {
"followers_count": 3526159,
"media_count": 3536,
"media": {
  "data": [
    {
      "timestamp": "2018-05-16T20:00:54+0000",
      "like_count": 28925,
      "comments_count": 530,
      "id": "17917935010179826"
    },

    (24 posts data omitted...)

    "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "after": "QVFIUlBNak5fNTc3eThl..." (a very long string)
    }
  }
}
```

Now, this only gives me the most recent 25 posts, which I believe is the limit per request set by Facebook.

What should I do if I want to load the next 25 posts?

In [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) there is also a limit per request of 50, but a "nextPageToken" is provided to load the next 50 post. I assume this is the same case here?

I also found in [this Facebook API document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/) that maybe I can add a cursor string like: `&after=QVFIUlBNak5fNTc3eThl...`,

but this doesn't work.

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: _“but this doesn't work”_ - then show a proper, full example of how you tried it, please.

Comment: I'd created days ago a bug request on developers facebook, you can check it here https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1951582745171480/

Seems that this endpoint is still under-construction...  Days ago paging information have `next`, `after`, `before` and `previous` info like others graph.facebook calls, all of this paging information was pointing to `/media` endpoint, thus is not accessible and neither correct. 
But they'd changed this behaviour without noticing anybody returning only an invalid `after` cursor.

Comment: @CBroe There are no differences whether I add the "after" or not

Comment: @jordivador I read your bug request, and honestly, I don't understand their response. If I understand the situation correctly, the `after` token is provided so manual pagination can be made when sending out our next request; `next` provides a direct link. But somehow `next` is taken away and `after` is not usable?

Comment: @JacobC I don't understand their response either, in top of that the bug is not fixed and they'd closed the bug-report as "fixed" ...
In my tests, I have no luck adding `after` cursor and as I understand without `before` cursor, you cannot paginate to the past posts...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The pagination with business_discovery is a bit different from Facebook 
pagination.

There's no `next` and `previous` url's.

You need to add, `after` cursor as this example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/xxxx?fields=business_discovery.username(jacqehoward){id,name,username,website,profile_picture_url,biography,followers_count,media_count,media.after(QVFIUlZA5aTR5NTE4Y24tNW90VGZAPTVBtb0NpOEFPTlNLeklmVTEtUDZAfVnE0YnBhUVNOQ3BDaktzNHJBTENhTmVYLUV2SGJPZAVAxZA09hQ2NhUGdnUGFjMTNn){id,caption,comments_count,like_count,media_type,media_url,owner,timestamp}}
```

Note:

`media.after(after_cursor){media_fields}`

And if you want to paginate through `business_discovery` to the end you must add `after` cursors until there's only response with `previous` cursor. This is the mark that you reached the first post.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook may have made some updates since this was last answered, so the [business discovery format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50445586/10871073) did not work for me. I had to make a call using an `access_token`.

I have found the following pattern to work:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/{your-user-id}/media?fields=id,like_count,comments_count,timestamp&limit=25&after={after}&access_token={access_token}
```

You can adjust the [fields](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media) as you like.